# Telerik MVC Grid Window Builder

Tags: c#, .net, telerik-mvc

Telerik MVC Grid has this in the grid when trying to create a editing window.

I don't understand what the "Action configurator" is and how is it used?

GridEditingSettingsBuilder Window(Action configurator)

hopefully i am making sense here is the link to the API reference

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/m_telerik_web_mvc_ui_fluent_grideditingsettingsbuilder_1_window.html

.Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).Window(==== how do i pass something here or what)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fluent API for the Telerik UI tools for ASP.NET MVC provide many "configurators" that enable you to quickly configure various behaviors and settings.

In this case, "Action" is the type, and "configurator" is simply the API variable name. This is an API endpoint that allows you to take control over the pop-up Window provided by the Grid for row editing. To use it, you'd write code like this:

```
.Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).Window(w => w.Modal(true)))
```

Where "w" would give you access to all of the various Window configuration options (and there are a lot!). You can review a full list of the available config options by [examining the WindowBuilder members API](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/allmembers_t_telerik_web_mvc_ui_fluent_windowbuilder.html).

This pattern generally applies for all "configurators" with the Telerik Extensions.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Todd is correct, in the format of the editable attribute mentioned previously. It sure would be nice if the editable attribute was smart enough to make this data editable on it's own, but unfortunately it is not! Ultimately, you will need to right data access code in order to perform different actions.

The best way to understand how it is setup, is to ultimately take a look at an example.

Check out this example:

[Telerik Ajax Editing Example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editingajax)

In this example you will need to look at the View and Controller to understand what is needed to make this happen. Ultimately you will need to write CRUD operations on your controller, and link to those operations from you configuration code on your gridview.